# Compile error foreachBatch is not a member of DataStreamWriter even though on spark-shell it works

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use `foreachBatch` with spark structured streaming. I tried the code on `spark-shell` console and it worked without any problem but when I trying to compile code I'm getting below error.

> value foreachBatch is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
> [error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value foreachBatch'?
> [error]       .foreachBatch { (batchDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => batchDf

My code is something like this.

```
val query = finalStream
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batchDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => batchDf
      .write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
      .option("url", StreamingCfg.redshiftJdbcUrl)
      .option("dbtable", redshiftTableName)
      .option("aws_iam_role", StreamingCfg.redshiftARN)
      .option("tempdir", redshiftTempDir)
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()

    batchDf
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .partitionBy("date_key", "hour")
      .parquet(outputLocation);
  }
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(aggregationTime.seconds))
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointingLocation)
  .start()
```

Does anyone know what am I missing here ?

Little more on what I'm doing,
Reading two streams from kafka -> Making stream-stream join on them -> writing it to redshift and S3 at the same time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```scala
finalStream
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch( (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long ) => {
      
  })
```

If it works in spark-shell, you should double check the dependencies in your work(dev) environment. Make sure that it is able to load all the spark dependencies and is using the right version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out spark environment issue. I just check and my build environment was using spark 2.2. I updated to spark 2.4 and compile worked.